# How do I dismount my horse?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, the-elder-scrolls-5-skyrim-vr

In *Skyrim VR*, I'm stuck because I don't know how to dismount my horse. In normal *Skyrim*, I can press a key to dismount, but my HTC Vive does not have a keyboard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to this [reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/PSVR/comments/7ds75i/this_is_embarrassing_but_how_do_i_get_off_a_horse/):

> look down, point at the horse and press the move button

Answer (score 0):

Just doing a long press on the right trackpad will do it.  No need to look down at the horse.